# seizeTransporter Block out port stop working

Tags: anylogic

I am modelling earthmoving operation. Every trench agent seize two transporters, one excavator, and one truck. When truck is released it will do some other job before been seized again by the same trench. So this process repeat until the trench will be empty.

The process is occuring for two three times without any problem but after two three times the trench agent is not go out of the seizeTransporter block (the one that seize truck). I have a delay block after the seizeTransporter block and it use Maximum Capacity. So it should not be a problem and it should not prevent the seizeTransporter block out port to push the trench out.

I noticed this is hapenning when the truck stop to resolve a collision. It looks like the collision cannot be resolved and the truck stay where it is for ever. :))

[image]

I have tried so many things that could solve this problem but none of them works.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in the material-handling library `TransporterControl` element to override transporter conflicts after some time. Maybe reduce the default timeout of 10 model time units, see below:

[image]

Comment: It was 2 (minutes, model time units)  in my model. I reduced it to 1. But it did not solve the problem. The weird part is that the collisions will be solved in so many cases but it won't be solved for that Truck!!! The point is that  the same truck resolve collision once and the whole process goes well but in the second round, that truck is not able to resolve the collision.  I did not have this problem when I was using 8.7.2 version. Not sure if  it is a bug for 8.7.3 version.

Comment: check with support@anylogic.com, might well be, if it is reproducible.